# Converting properties to strings based on type

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write an algorithm that:

- Accepts any object as a parameter
- Iterates over all the public instance properties to determine their type including any nested properties (in the case where the property is a complex type (or a collection of complex types)
- Formats the property name and value as a string depending upon their type and indents the string for each level of nesting.

The class hierarchies can become quite deep in the domain I'm working in.  The following illustrates a simple case.  Note, all the classes are POCOs.  There isn't much behaviour with these objects, they just hold data.

```cs
public class ParentObject
{
  public string Name { get; set;}
  public IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, int>> { get; set; }
  public NestedObject { get; set; }
}

public class NestedObject
{
  public bool IsIt { get; set; }
}
```

My first attempt takes in the `ParentObject` and convert it to a string by comparing the type of each property:

```cs
public string CustomFormat(object obj)
{
  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (var property in obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
  {
    if (property.GetType() == typeof(string))
      sb.AppendLine(CustomFormatString(property.Name, (string)property.GetValue(obj));
    if (property.GetType() == typeof(int))
      sb.AppendLine(CustomFormatString(property.Name, (int)property.GetValue(obj));
    // ... keep going
  }
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

I've hit a couple of snags:

1. When I get to formatting properties that implement `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` the casting becomes really messy.
2. I hear a voice in my head going this is not a good way to do this every time I make another keystroke.

In my research I've read about the Visitor Pattern and Double Dispatch.  That seems like a cleaner way to approach this, but I'm not confident I'm implementing it correctly because I still end up needing to do the type casting eventually.

Vistor Pattern approach:

```cs
public interface IVisitor
{
    void VisitParent(Parent parent);
}

public abstract class Parent
{
    public abstract void Accept(IVisitor visitor);
}

public class ParentObject : Parent
{
  public string Name { get; set;}
  public IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, int>> { get; set; }
  public NestedObject { get; set; }

  public override void Accept(IVisitor visitor)
  {
    visitor.VisitResource(this);
  }
}

public class CustomFormatVisitor : IVisitor
{
  public void VisitParent(Parent parent)
  {
    // Still end up implementing the type casting logic here
    // If string then ...
    // If Dictionary then ...
    // etc...
  }
}
```

So then I thought, what if I implement classes that handle the formatting, and implement them as the type on the class:

```cs
public class ParentObject
{
  public CustomString Name { get; set;}
  public CustomDictionary<string, CutomDictionary<string, int>> { get; set; }
  public NestedObject { get; set; }
}

public class CustomString
{
  private string _value;
  CustomString(string value) => _value = value;
  public string ToString(string key)
  {
    // Custom formatting logic
  }
}
```

But with this approach I don't like the way I've coupled the formatting of the property to the `ParentObject` class.

Is there a design pattern or data structure that looks like a good fit for this type of problem?  Even pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered [Examples of XML Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization)?

Comment: I have not. Will check it out, thanks.

Comment: There is also a [How to serialize and deserialize (marshal and unmarshal) JSON in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0) if that is preferred

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a read of these tomorrow. To be clear, I'm not looking to output JSON or XML. Or are you suggesting I look at the implementations for inspiration?

Comment: Well, once you have serialized to JSON or xml, you can simply parse that text, it contains all the string you need.

Comment: You never said one way or the other for serialisation, figured that Xml or JSon maybe viable alternatives. However, both of those methods can help you come up with a [Custom serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/custom-serialization) which may be better for you in the long run.